# Sorting eigenvectors according to its projection

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra

**The problem**

I'm trying to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix that depends on a parameter `x`. As `x` changes, I get a series of eigenvalues and eigenvectors corresponding to different x. Then I need to sort the eigenvalues and eigenvectors so that I get a continuous change. I can make it work, but the **code runs too slow**. Here are the details:

This is the function that generates the matrix that depends on `x`

```
H[x_,nBlock_:21] := Module[{tridiag, diagL, diag},
  tridiag = {{0, x/2}, {x/2, 0}};
  diag = {{-1/2, 0}, {0, 1/2}};
  diagL = IdentityMatrix[{2, 2}];
  SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 
     Table[diag + diagL*(i - nBlock/2), {i, 1/2, nBlock - 1/2}], 
    Band[{3, 1}] -> Table[tridiag, {nBlock - 1}], 
    Band[{1, 3}] -> Table[tridiag, {nBlock - 1}]}]
  ]
```

For a specific `x`, we calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and sort them according to the eigenvalue. Then we do this for a series of `x` values.

```
{valls, vecls} = 
  Transpose@Table[
    Transpose@SortBy[Transpose[Eigensystem[H[x]]], First], {x, 0.1, 5, 0.1}];
```

Here is what the 19th to 24th eigenvalues look like, as a function of x. We can see that there are some "avoided" crossings in the eigenvalues (notice how the colors change near those crossings).

```
ListPlot[Transpose[valls][[19 ;; 24]], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

And the goal is to fix that by reordering the eigenvalues and eigenvectors in each x so that the eigenvalues look like this (notice the colors of the curve)

```
ListPlot[Transpose[valSortls][[19 ;; 24]], Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The algorithm for reorderring is like this: Say we have eigenvectors `{v1,v2,v3,...}` corresponding to the matrix `H[x]`, and `{u1,u2,u3...}` corresponding to `H[x+dx]`, and we want to reorderring `{u1,u2,u3...}` based on `{v1,v2,v3,...}`. Then the correct vector at the first place should be the one in `{u1,u2,u3...}` that has the largest projection on `v1`. For example, if `u1` is the correct vector, then it should satisfy `Abs[Conjugate[v1].u1]>Abs[Conjugate[v1].u2]` and `Abs[Conjugate[v1].u1]>Abs[Conjugate[v1].u3]`.  The same is true for the other vectors in `{u1,u2,u3...}`. Moreover, I know that the crossing only happens between the neighbors.

**My implementation**

I tried a rudimentary implementation:

a function sort two vector lists, and return the ordering index:

```
sortVecs[vecls1_, vecls2_] := Module[{vecSort, lth, veclth, neib},
  lth = Length[vecls1];
  Table[
   neib = Select[{n - 1, n, n + 1}, lth >= # >= 1 &];
   First@Last[
     SortBy[Transpose[{neib, vecls2[[neib]]}], 
      Abs[Conjugate[vecls1[[n]]].#[[2]]] &]]
   , {n, 1, lth}]
  ]
```

and the function that sorts both the eigenvectors and eigenvalues:

```
sortEigensystem[{valls_, vecls_}] := 
 Module[{lth = Length[valls], vallsSorted, veclsSorted, vec, val, ordering},
  vallsSorted = {};
  veclsSorted = {};
  vec = vecls[[1]];(*list of vectors being sorted*)
  val = valls[[1]];(*the corresponding values being sorted*)
  veclsSorted = Append[veclsSorted, vec];
  vallsSorted = Append[vallsSorted, val];

  Table[

   ordering = sortVecs[vec, vecls[[n + 1]]];
   vec = vecls[[n + 1]][[ordering]];
   val = valls[[n + 1]][[ordering]];

   veclsSorted = Append[veclsSorted, vec];(*append the sorted vectors*)
   vallsSorted = Append[vallsSorted, val];(*append the sorted values*)

   , {n, 1, lth - 1}];

  {vallsSorted, veclsSorted}

  ]
```

Here is a test

```
{valSortls, vecSortls} = sortEigensystem[{valls, vecls}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.030064, Null} *)
```

**Question**

How can I make sortEigensystem run faster? For my real situation, I need to sort about 1000 400X400 matrixes.

```
{valls, vecls} = 
   Transpose@
    Table[Transpose@SortBy[Transpose[Eigensystem[H[x,201]]], First], {x, 
      0.1, 10, 0.01}];
{valSortls, vecSortls} = 
   sortEigensystem[{valls, vecls}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {27.7415, Null} *)
```

I would like to reduce the time to less than 10 seconds if that is possible.

Comment: You may try this solution http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39754/193 .Not sure if the question is an exact dup

Comment: @xslittlegrass - in your example, it takes only 30 milliseconds, which is not long.  I assume you need to do this on either much matrices (larger than 42 by 42) or for many more x-values than 50.  What are you looking to do with this in the end, that this is the choke-point timewise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get eigenvectors without phase jump?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-get-eigenvectors-without-phase-jump)

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of [1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-get-eigenvectors-without-phase-jump), [2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41334/mixing-up-eigenvalues-with-positive-and-negative-imaginary-parts), and [3](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83906/reordering-numerically-calculated-eigenvalues-assuming-smooth-dependence-on-a-pa) (and maybe others).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I think this is different than [How get eigenvectors without phase jump](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-get-eigenvectors-without-phase-jump) since there we are dealing with the phase of the eigenvectors, whereas we are dealing with the orders of the eigenvectors here. But I agree the question is the same as in [3](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83906/reordering-numerically-calculated-eigenvalues-assuming-smooth-dependence-on-a-pa).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau However, I'm asking more of the better coding style/performance tuning rather than the algorithm of how to do that. It's quite common that we need to sort some list of according to some general rules, and adjust a second list at the same time. While my implementation already works well, it's somewhat clumsy and not elegant as I hope. I'm wondering whether there is some standard (faster) way to do this kind of sorting in Mathematica.

Comment: Okay, I'll undo my "close as duplicate" vote based on that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just tried to clean up the code a bit.  With respect to `sortVecs`, I used `Ordering` which is really what you were going for.  You were wasting a little bit of time by taking the conjugate of one of the vectors, when the eigenvectors in `vecls` are all real-valued.  Should you move to a different form for `H` that gives complex eigenvectors, just uncomment the relevant part below.

In `sortEigensystem` you were using `x=Append[x,newval]`, which is equivalent to `AppendTo[x,newval]` which should be avoided as it is a time waste - (I think because at each step it needs to find the end of the list and then tack on a new bit). Use `Reap` and `Sow` instead (or even `Table` if possible, but in this case `Table` is slower than `Reap` and `Sow`).

Those changes made it about 2 to 2.5 times faster, depending on the size of the system, but I was able to make it much faster by compiling the `sortVecs` function.

Here are the new versions of `sortVecs` and `sortEigensystem`:

```
sortVecsComp = Compile[{{vecls1, _Real, 2}, {vecls2, _Real, 2}},
   Module[{vecSort, lth, neib}, lth = Length[vecls1];
    Table[neib = Select[{n - 1, n, n + 1}, lth >= # >= 1 &];
     neib[[Last@Ordering[Abs[((*Conjugate@*)vecls1[[n]]).#] & /@ 
          vecls2[[neib]]]]], {n, 1, lth}]]
   ];

sortEigensystem2[{valls_, vecls_}] := 
 Module[{lth = Length[valls], vallsSorted, veclsSorted, vec, val, 
   ordering,va,ve},
  vec = vecls[[1]];(*list of vectors being sorted*)

  val = valls[[1]];(*the corresponding values being sorted*)
  Reap[
    Do[
     ordering = sortVecsComp[vec, vecls[[n]]];
     vec = vecls[[n]][[ordering]];
     val = valls[[n]][[ordering]];
     Sow[val, va];
     Sow[vec, ve];
     , {n, 1, lth}]][[2]]
  ];
```

Here is an example on $400\times 400$ matrices,

```
(* I have to use Quiet here because it shouts errors about the fact that it's 
easier to run Eigensystem on normal arrays than on SparseArrays of this size *)
Quiet[{valls, vecls} = 
  Transpose@Table[Transpose@SortBy[Transpose[Eigensystem[H[x, 201]]], First], {x, 0.1, 10, 0.01}];]

{valSortls, vecSortls} = 
   sortEigensystem[{valls, vecls}]; // AbsoluteTiming
{valSortls2, vecSortls2} = 
   sortEigensystem2[{valls, vecls}]; // AbsoluteTiming
{valSortls2, vecSortls2} == {valSortls, vecSortls}

(* {25.1059, Null} *)

(* {1.83797, Null}  *)

(* True   *)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't get such a large speedup as you did. I got 2.5X speedup, which is already very good.

Comment: Is that before or after I edited and made changes to 'sortVecs'?

Comment: After your edit on Oct 2.

Comment: Just tried it again, and the dramatic results I had before weren't  reproducible.  Now I would only get a speedup of 2 to 3 times faster.  But I couldn't let that be, so I tried to compile the `sortVecs` function, and it's loads faster now.

Comment: OK, that's impressive. I was too focused onto the form of the programing and forgot the `Compile` trick. Thanks!

Comment: Just a small improvement, you'll have to compile for `Complex` terms if you're operating with a complex `Eigensystem`--while I don't know if this _actually_ worked yet (will plot in morning), it gave me true where it was supposed to, being uncrossed, and when I enticed crossings it gave me false, when checking if sorted and unsorted were equal. This is good, and it runs extremely fast for 100 50x50 matrices. I learned a lot, and am extremely thankful for this problem. +1's all around!!